# Is there a word or phrase for an insult that is presented as "I would never call" which is a meaningless denial in context?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

<sub>This question has been closed as a duplicate because it has an answer elsewhere, but anyone who wishes to write a new answer is most welcome to post it under the original question, possibly referencing this question in your new answer to avoid any confusion.</sub>

---

I have heard some people insult others explicitly with the rider "I would never call" which is a meaningless denial in context because the person is effectively ***calling*** them that right then and there, as in

> I would never call you a dull, idiotic bigot...
>
> I would never call my learned opponent fat, ugly and ignorant...

Alternate form kindly reminded by @Fattie in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/430979/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-for-an-insult-that-is-presented-as-i-would-never-call#comment1034116_430979):

> "Many people have said she is XZY [insult] - but of course I'd never say that!"

This is often heard in a political context but also in personal interactions. Is there a word or phrase to describe this?

Phrases I have considered and rejected: It is ***not*** a [veiled](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/veiled) insult or a [qualified insult](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22qualified+insult%22&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&oq=%22qualified+insult%22&gs_) because the insult is not veiled/ qualified but explicit, and it is not a [backhanded compliment](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/backhanded) because it is not a mitigated compliment or an insult with potential to carry a compliment, but is an outright, unmitigated insult.

***Update***: Thanks to @Edwin Ashworth for marking as duplicate and pointing to the earlier question: of those 4 answers the word [apophasis](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/240500/231519) seems very appropriate for this context based on the insulting political examples provided in the article linked: https://thoughtco.com/what-is-apophasis-rhetoric-1689115