# What is the word for implying something by denying it?

Tags: american-english, british-english

There is a word that describes the act of implying something via a denial of that same thing. I have forgotten the word and can no longer find it online using my search-fu. What is the word?

eg: "The papers say he is a rascal. I would never say that!"

Comment: Possibly "paralipsis".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should we call language that intentionally conveys the opposite of the literal meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240317/what-should-we-call-language-that-intentionally-conveys-the-opposite-of-the-lite) Also [Is there a word or phrase for an insult that is presented as "I would never call ..., but ..."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/430979/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-for-an-insult-that-is-presented-as-i-would-never-call) {"I would never call you a dull, idiotic bigot, but ...." ...}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia *apophasis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophasis)

> Apophasis (/əˈpɒfəsɪs/; Greek: ἀπόφασις from ἀπόφημι apophemi,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophasis) "to say no")[2] is a rhetorical device wherein the speaker or writer brings up a subject by either denying it, or denying that it should be brought up.[3] Accordingly, it can be seen as a rhetorical relative of irony.
> The device is also called paralipsis (παράλειψις) – also spelled paraleipsis or paralepsis – or occupatio,[4][5][6][7] and known also as praeteritio, preterition, or parasiopesis (παρασιώπησις).

(The number are references within the Wikipedia article.)

Incidentally, this Wikipedia reference was the second link on a DuckDuckGo search on your exact phrase:

> What is the word for implying something by denying it?

The first hit was your post here.

Comment: That's it. Thank you!

Comment: Please check for duplicates. It's contrary to ELU's mission statement to have multiple repeats; for one thing, it usually makes searching harder.